# Can someone help me with physical address of list elements (C#)?

Tags: c#, linked-list

I need to create a project in C# to show how linked list works.

I'm thinking to make something like this:

```
root -> (address ffff) value: 5; next: fff1; 
                  -> (address fff1) value: 4; next: fff2;
```

... and so on...
Is this possible in C#? Can someone show me how it's done?

Ok, here is what I have so far:

```
class ListaSI
{
    public class element
    {
        public element next = null;
        public object data;
    }

    private element root = null;

    public element First { get { return root; } }

    public element Last
    {
        get
        {
            element currentElement = root;
            if (currentElement == null)
                return null;
            while (currentElement.next != null)
                currentElement = currentElement.next;
            return currentElement;
        }
    }

    // basic operations ( add, delete, etc... )
```

Well, I need address for "data" field. I try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcbcf4ta%28v=vs.80%29.aspx , but it won't work.

Doesn't let me to do this:

```
int *p = &currentElement.next;  // I'm sure this is wrong! :)
```

But I need something like that ?

Here is what i try:

```
public string displayList()
    {
        string myString = "";
        element currentElement = this.root;
        while (true)
        {
            if (currentElement.next != null)
            {
                // i'm stuck here
            }



        }

        return myString;
    }
```

Comment: Worth noting that in C# you're usually dealing with references that may change, not physical addresses.

Comment: @Abrixas2 I think his question is valid. If you do not use unsafe in C#, how to create linked list?

Comment: @PranitKothari I did not state his question is invalid, it just does not show any attempt to find an answer before asking here.

Comment: Welcome to `c#`, a language the typically runs in a managed environment. You don't need to know about memory addresses to describe how a linked list works. If you want to talk about memory addresses, use a language that exposes this information without needing to resort to unsafe code. Trying to do so using C# is a distraction.

Comment: You could create a 'virtual memory' using a managed array of objects.  These would actually be references to whatever you put in there, but it'll be good for this purpose.  You then use the index of each element in the array as it's address.  The list elements would then include a 'next' (and 'prev') which is the index of the respective element in the array.

Comment: In your example, instead of having the `data` field as an int, have it as an `object`.  this will be a reference (managed pointer) to an instance of whatever class you're using it to store.  You can then move on to type-safe generics and make it a `ListaSI<T>` abstract class, with data being of type `T`.

Comment: Thank you @Mike of SST, this could be a solution. Can you give me some basic code, just for helping me to understand...i don't have so much experience with c#, this is my first semester with this programming language..

Comment: @user3122210 I could, if the question were not closed.  Have a look at my second comment and see if that helps too.  It's probably closer to what you want anyway.

Comment: @MikeofSST can you take a look on displayList() function and help me out? I'm stuck there, i don't understand how to use reference of that "object data".

Comment: If you've added a String when you created the new list item e.g. `currentElement.data = myString;` then you access it similarly: `myString = currentElement.data as String;`  When using the `as` operator, if the cast from `object` to `String` fails then the detination reference will be set as `null`, which you can test for.  If you use a cast `myString = (String)currentElement.data;` the cast will be made even if the underlying types are incompatible and you'll get an exception when you try to use it as a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point having an element without a data item, so you should modify the `element` constructor to include a parameter for the data item.

```
public class element
{
    public element next = null;
    public object data = null;

    public element(object dataItem)
    {
        this.data = dataItem;
    }
}
```

Then to access the content of the list, using your displayList method - I've made a few assumptions about what you want to display, but you'll get the idea.

```
public string displayList()
{
    // Use a StringBuilder to concatenate strings from the list
    StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();

    // Iterate through the list, starting at the root.
    element currentElement = this.root;
    while (currentElement != null)
    {
        // Add the data item from the current element
        String dataString = currentElement.data as String;
        if(null != dataString)
        {
            myString.Add(dataString + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            myString.Add("null" + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        // Try the next element in the list.
        currentElement = currentElement.next;
    }

    return myString.ToString();
}
```

To clarify about pointers and C#, there are ways to get a pointers in C# (search for `IntPtr` and `PInvoke` here on SO for examples: there are many), but in general you do not need them.  As mentioned in comments, C# is a managed language that provides you with object references instead of pointers, handling most of the `malloc`, `free` and other nasties associated with pointers and dynamic memory allocation (caveat: look into IDisposable interface, as this is not universally true, especically when dealing with non-managed resources such as handles to some kinds of streams, database sessions, etc.).  When you declare a variables as any type derived from `System.Object` the variable will be a reference to the object, rather than the object itself.  Hence object members are accessed by `object.member` with no C# version of the `object->member` operator that you will find in C and C++.

(The above explanation is somewhat simplified and I've made several sweeping generalisations, but the subject is far broader than could be covered by this short answer and there are many good books if you require further reading.)